# SYMFONY -- Generate CRUD: entity doesn't exist but already created

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, crud

I'm having trouble to generate a CRUD for my entity.

**[[RuntimeException]
  Entity "Post" does not exist in the "PlatypusBundle" bundle. You may have mistyped the bundle name or maybe the entity doesn't exist yet (create it first with the "doctrine:generate:entity" command).]**

Thing is, I already generated the entity, when I'm trying to re-create it, it says that it already exists.
Driving me crazy.

So, here is my question? What am I supposed to do to be able to create my CRUD? Would someone have a solution, besides deleting everything and trying to re-create it?

I already tried to generate a form and it didn't work saying my entity didn't exist. I checked if everything was correctly typed, and I'm pretty sure it is.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Symfony CLI and the form manager says the entity doesn't exist, please add your entity code (and which folder it's stored in). Assuming you're running a dev environment / have cleared cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error may be from Many causes:

1) Check your `Entity` class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="post") // you have to check in Database exists or not?
 */
class Post
```

2) You have to run `command` update schema:

a. `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` // show your status database if have some changes shows

b. If you have some changes from database run command `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Then You can run `CRUD` command.

Comment: Indeed, the table doesn't exist in my db, but when I update --force or --dump-sql it says i'm already up to date ... should I create the table by myself??

Answer (score 1):

FOUND THE PROBLEM !

Okay, so my problem was that I created 2 entities but not with the same configuration format (one in YML, the other in annotation). So indeed, nothing was created correctly and Symfony didn't get the differences .. Anyway I had a save of my project that I took and created the new entity with the good config format !
Otherwise, the answer of KorozCo would have been the perfect solution !!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using SonataAdminBundle (like me), I solved this issue by adding my bundle in config.yml, to be more specific, here is the code :

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    entity_managers:
        default:
            mappings:

                ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                SonataUserBundle: ~
                ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
                SonataMediaBundle: ~
                ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle: ~
                SonataClassificationBundle: ~
                ApplicationSonataNewsBundle: ~
                SonataNewsBundle: ~
                BackBundle: ~
                MyCustomBundle: ~ # here I where I added my custom Bundle
```